# How to instantiate javax.security.X509Certficate object from a p12 certificate (contains certificate + private key)

Tags: x509certificate, pkcs#12

X509Certificate is only instantiatable using the contents of a certificate (.cer file). How to instantiate this object using a .p12 file that contains both the certificate and the private key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("c:/certificate.p12");

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(inStream, "password".toCharArray());  

String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
```

Comment: This assumes there is only one cert in the keystore, otherwise you'll need to specify the alias directly.

Comment: Hi, Any idea how one might do this for Blackberry? For Java in Blackberry, the KeyStore class doesn't have the getInstance(String) method available. I have posted a separate question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151134/how-to-instantiate-x509certificate-from-a-p12-file-in-blackberry

Comment: Just remember to use java.security.* classes instead of javax.security.*